# How do I write an "API Gateway as a proxy for DynamoDB" with Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, serverless, serverless-framework

I've just came across this thing I didn’t know exists: “API Gateway as a proxy for DynamoDB” (ref: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/)

I want to replace my lambdas to this^

All my requests are pretty simple, except of my GET request that have some built-in customised filters (possible combinations of get by column, date range, etc)

I did come across the plugin “apigateway-service-proxy”, but not sure if this will be sufficient for my future needs, and prefer to apply this in a “raw” custom way while merging it to my current api gateway (v2 aka HTTP API).

If it’s possible to get some kind of a boiler plate template on how to apply this in `serverless.yml` (and i guess this will include some code? Preferably in python, but now a must, i just want to understand how to structure my `.yml` file to accept dynamodb as proxy for the api). References to sources that include the relevant information are super welcome, I didn't find any.

**EDIT:**

Since my post was flagged with "need more focus", I will write down some of my use cases. My API should respond as such:

1. GET requests to `/devices`:

   - `/devices` - should return all the devices in my dynamodb table.
   - `/devices?customer_id=42` - should return all devices with customer_id column equals to 42.
   - `/devices?customer_id=null` - *(could be any other indicator that isn't null but similar, I know `Number` type field doesn't have "null"s)* returns all devices that doesn't have a "customer_id" column.
   - `/devices?created=12345,67899` - returns all devices created between the 2 timestamps.
   - Combinations of more than one filter, like `/devices?customer_id=42&created=12345,67899` - will return all devices assigned to user id 42 and created between the 2 stated timestamps.
2. POST request for `/devices`: Adds a device row in the Devices dynamodb table, while some inputs like "customer_id, name, url" are mandatory.
3. PATCH request for `/devices`: Updates a row in `Devices` table. Can be one or more of the following columns: "name, url, customer_id" while customer_id can be an non existing column too.

Note: The solution doesn't have to include all the requests i mentioned, although, the more the better. I can build a function that builds a filter. I just need the general guidelines for doing that with Serverless Framework.

Answer (score 0):

One helpful plugin in the Serverless Framework ecosystem is `serverless-apigateway-service-proxy`:

https://github.com/serverless-operations/serverless-apigateway-service-proxy

You can define service integration in the `custom` key:

```yaml
custom:
  apiGatewayServiceProxies:
    - dynamodb:
        path: /dynamodb/{id}/{sort}
        method: put
        tableName: { Ref: 'YourTable' }
        hashKey: # set pathParam or queryStringParam as a partitionkey.
          pathParam: id
          attributeType: S
        rangeKey: # required if also using sort key. set pathParam or queryStringParam.
          pathParam: sort
          attributeType: S
        action: PutItem # specify action to the table what you want
        condition: attribute_not_exists(Id) # optional Condition Expressions parameter for the table
        cors: true
    - dynamodb:
        path: /dynamodb
        method: get
        tableName: { Ref: 'YourTable' }
        hashKey:
          queryStringParam: id # use query string parameter
          attributeType: S
        rangeKey:
          queryStringParam: sort
          attributeType: S
        action: GetItem
        cors: true
    - dynamodb:
        path: /dynamodb/{id}
        method: delete
        tableName: { Ref: 'YourTable' }
        hashKey:
          pathParam: id
          attributeType: S
        action: DeleteItem
        cors: true

resources:
  Resources:
    YourTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: YourTable
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: sort
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: sort
            KeyType: RANGE
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

Otherwise, you need to define **mapping templates** for request and response and create API Gateway resources via CloudFormation using the `AWS` integration.

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#lambda-integration

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-integration-types.html

- `AWS`: This type of integration lets an API expose AWS service actions. In AWS integration, you must configure both the integration request and integration response and set up necessary data mappings from the method request to the integration request, and from the integration response to the method response.